# Plotting contours of a two-variable function containing a sum

Tags: plotting, series-expansion, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to use Mathematica to plot contours of a rather intricate two-variable function. The equation describes the velocity profile for laminar flow in a tube of rectangular section, namely:
$$
{w^ * }\left( {x,y} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {{a^2} - {y^2}} \right) + \frac{2}{a}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}}}{{\alpha _n^3}}\cos \left( {{\alpha _n}y} \right)\frac{{\cosh \left( {{\alpha _n}x} \right)}}{{\cosh \left( {{\alpha _n}} \right)}}}
$$
In this equation, *x* is the horizontal coordinate, *y* is the vertical coordinate, *w* is the axial velocity, *a* is the aspect ratio of the rectangular section, and ${\alpha _n}$ is a coefficient given by
$$ {\alpha _n} = \frac{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)\pi }}{{2a}} $$
Here's how the velocity contours should look like for a section with *a* = 0.5:
[image]

I began by programming coefficient ${\alpha _n}$,

```
\[Alpha] = ((2*i - 1)*\[Pi])/(2*a);
```

Then, I tried programming the function for *w*. Note that I want the function to be such that the user can specify an aspect ratio *a* (third input) and a number *NN* of terms in the summation that appears in *w(x,y)* (fourth input):

```
     squareDuct[x_, y_, a_, NN_] := 1/2*(a^2 - y^2) + 
   2/a*Sum[(-1)^i/\[Alpha]^3*Cosh[\[Alpha]*y]*Cosh[\[Alpha]*x]/
      Cosh[\[Alpha]], {i, NN}];
```

Then, I tried using `ContourPlot` by setting the function to 0.01 and using an aspect ratio *a* = 0.5 with *NN* = 15 terms in the sum:

```
ContourPlot[
 squareDuct[x, y, 0.5, 15] == 0.01, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}, 
 Contours -> 20]
```

Unfortunately, all I got was that empty blank frame that signals there's something wrong with the code. I believe the problem with my approach has to do with the *a priori* definition of coefficient ${\alpha _n}$, or maybe the `Sum` command within the function. I def. could use some help on how to program *w(x,y)* and the associated contours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `With[{a = 1/2, n = 15}, ContourPlot[(a^2 - y^2)/2 + (2/a) Sum[With[{α = (2 k - 1) π/(2 a)}, (-1)^k/α^3 Cos[α y] Cosh[α x]/Cosh[α]], {k, 1, n}] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None]]` gives the picture I expected.

Comment: As @J.M. indicated, you used `Cosh` where `Cos` should be.